# Binary Search Tree in C- search cannot return message if value not found

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I tried to make a binary search tree with recursion. I've only written out the insert and search functionality. However, my search function is faulty. I'm stuck on line 39, where if I do not find the value present in my tree, it doesn't return me the message that the value is not found. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node { 
    int key; 
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;

struct node* root= NULL;

int contains(node* temp, int el){

        if (el==temp->key) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(el< temp->key) return contains(temp->left, el);
        else return contains(temp->right, el);
}

void searchPrompt(void){
    int el=-1;
    do{
        printf("   Search key or press -1 to return to menu: ");
        scanf("%d", &el);
        if(el>0){
            if (root==NULL) printf("\tError: tree is empty\n"); 
            else {
                if(contains(root, el)) printf("\tKey %d is found\n",el);
                else printf("\tKey %d is not found\n",el);
            }
        }
        else if (el<-1||el==0) printf("\tError: key not positive\n");
    }while (el!=-1);
    printf("   <Exit search method>\n\n");
}
//for search

void preOrder(node* temp){

    if (temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->key);
        preOrder(temp->left);
        preOrder(temp->right);
    }
}

//for insertion
void insertNode(node* current, int value){        
        if(value< current->key){
            if (current->left == NULL) {
                current->left=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
                current->left->key = value;
                printf("\tSuccess! Value inserted: %d\n", current->left->key);

            }
            else {
                insertNode(current->left, value);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (current->right == NULL) {
                current->right=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
                current->right->key = value;
                printf("\tSuccess! Value inserted: %d\n", current->right->key);
            }
            else {
                insertNode(current->right, value);
            }
        }
}//end insert

void insert(int value){

    if(root==NULL){  //empty tree
        root =(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));

        root->key= value;
        printf("\tPrint root here: %d\n", value);
        root->left= NULL;
        root->right=NULL;
        printf("\tSuccess! Value inserted: %d\n", root->key);
    }
    else {
        insertNode(root, value);
    }        
        printf("\tResult: ");
        preOrder(root);
        printf("\n");
}

void insertPrompt(void){
    int value=-1;
    do{
        printf("   Insert value or press -1 to return to menu:  ");
        scanf("%d", &value);
        if(value>0)
            insert(value);
        else if (value<=0)printf("\tError: key not positive\n");
    }while (value!=-1);
    printf("   <Exit insert method>\n\n");

}

int menuPrompt(void){
    int choice=-1;
    do{
        printf("Enter <1> Search <2> Insert <3> Delete <4> Print Tree <5> Quit: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if(choice>5 || choice<1) printf("Error: invalid input! \n\n");
    }  while(choice>5 || choice<1);
    return choice;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   int choice=-1;
   int value=-1;


    while(choice!=5){

   choice=menuPrompt();

   switch(choice){
    case 1:
         searchPrompt();
         break;
    case 2:
         insertPrompt();
         break;
    case 3:

         break;
    case 4:

         break;    
    case 5:
         printf("<Exit program> \n");
         break;
   }//end switch

}

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `contains` function has undefined behavior when passed a NULL pointer, which will happen whenever you search for a key that isn't in the tree.

Comment: Or from a different angle, your `contains()` function has no condition under which it returns 0.  Recursing doesn't magically create such a condition.

Comment: Also `insertNode` need set `NULL` to `right` and `left` of new node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int contains(node* temp, int el){
        if(temp==NULL) return 0;
        if (el==temp->key) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if(el< temp->key) return contains(temp->left, el);
        else return contains(temp->right, el);
}
```

This solved both the problem ..saves you from UB and also from wrong behavior in case elemnt not found.

At **BLUEPIXY** mentioned set left and right inserted new node to `NULL`.

> why is it needed you might ask ..but the thing is when you don't find
>   an element eventually you will reach some leaf node. And then you will
>   go to left or right and if you set it to NULL you will call `contain`
>   with `NULL` as parameter and then it will return 0 as you expect it to
>   be.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY.: I didnt got the insert thing..you can write an answer..then I will remove mine

Answer (score 0):

```
//for insertion
void insertNode(node* current, int value){        
        if(value< current->key){
            if (current->left == NULL) {
                current->left=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
                current->left->key = value;
                current->left->left = NULL;
                current->left->right = NULL;
                printf("\tSuccess! Value inserted: %d\n", current->left->key);

            }
            else {
                insertNode(current->left, value);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (current->right == NULL) {
                current->right=(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
                current->right->key = value;
                current->right->left = NULL;
                current->right->right = NULL;
                printf("\tSuccess! Value inserted: %d\n", current->right->key);
            }
            else {
                insertNode(current->right, value);
            }
        }
}//end insert
```

Is this what I needed to do with the left and right of my new node? @BLUEPIXY @coderredoc